# Ayuda con un trigger - insersión [SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Necesito una inserción de empleados en donde una tabla llamada `Control_Datos` y cuando se inserte un empleado se copien los datos sobre la inserción de la tabla `Control_Datos`.

```
create trigger DatosEmpleados
ON Control_Empleados 
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT empleados
```

Comment: Indica por favor el gestor de bases de datos que usas

Comment: El gestor es SQL SERVER

Comment: Ok compañera, ahora sería bueno para tu pregunta agregues una descripción por ejemplo de: ¿qué errores presenta el código actual, qué resultados devuelve y cuáles son los esperados?

Comment: Por ahora no ha arrojado errores ya que no se ha completado el código, Tengo una tabla llamada Control_Empleados. y una tabla empleados, se necesita hacer un INSERT a cada uno para que se guarden los datos de empleados a la tabla control_empleados

Comment: Necesitas mostrar la estructura de las tablas que tienes (empleados y control_datos). De otra forma, lo más que se logra es un ejemplo genérico como el que encuentras [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/triggers/create-dml-triggers-to-handle-multiple-rows-of-data?view=sql-server-2017).